# Theming Bootstrap 5.3 with Sass and not including everything,

Tags: css, sass, bootstrap-5

In [docs/5.3/customize/sass/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/customize/sass/), Bootstrap give two options for importing the source sass files in order to customise the CSS.

**Option A:** include everything:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**Option B:** in their words - pick the parts you need and this is the option they encourage.

I've been attempting to customise the colors and the following doesn't work for buttons although links and the basic link button are updated. I tested a version where heading 4 contents were above 3 with no change.

```
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here
$primary: #ff74d9;
$danger: #004136;

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets (inc. color mode stylesheets)
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables-dark";

// 4. Include any default map overrides here
$theme-colors: (
        primary: $primary,
);


// 5. Include remainder of required parts
@import "../bootstrap/scss/maps";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../bootstrap/scss/root";

// 6. Optionally include any other parts as needed
// NONE

// 7. Optionally include utilities API last to generate classes based on the Sass map
// NONE

// 8. Add additional custom code here
```

Where as this does work but includes everything in the none encouraged way:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option A: Include all of Bootstrap

// Include any default variable overrides here (though functions won't be available)
$primary: #ff74d9;
$danger: #004136;

$theme-colors: (
        primary: $primary,
);

@import "../bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

// Then add additional custom code here
```

Assuming that color and font style customisation is the most common form of theming that takes place what imports are required?